# How to keep the value of variables during calling php functions

Tags: php, html

I am using a php functions file to set the value of a global variable but I missed this value when i call the function in other php file using include("functions.php");

I am doing this:

```
////File1.php////

include("functions.php");

$data_person = $_POST['data_person'];//here i am getting 'data_person' from a form, it works fine

receive_DP($data_person);//Here I send the variable

show_DP();//It shows the values inside $data_person



////functions.php////

$data_person;

function receive_DP($data_person_array)
{
    global $data_person;

    $data_person = $data_person_array;


}

function show_DP()
{

   global $data_person;

   echo "name:".$data_person[0];
   echo "last name:".$data_person[1];
   echo "age".$data_person[2];
}

//then i go to File2.php with a FORM (input submit) and i need to keep the values in $data_person
//It is like a header, It shows personal info, It is supposed to be the values of this variable   
//are set and they should be always



////File2.php////     HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I MISSED THE VALUES OF $data_persona 

include("functions.php");

show_DP();//It shows nothing, just name:, last name: and age:, but not the the values
```

Like I said i am getting the values from a form tag, then i am passing them to File1.php and getting the values with $_POST, it works fine, I call both functions (receive_DP() and show_DP() ) and it works fine next i go to File2.php with a button but when i call show_DP() function the values are gone.

Comment: store your value in session, than you can access them any where you want

Comment: I thought of that, but i dont know How to work with $_SESSION(), please, explain me quickly How i should do here, thanks

Comment: in which file you are getting the value, and in which file you want to access it. Thanks reply me i will tell you

Comment: I getting the values with $_POST in file1.php, next i send the variable to the function receive_DP and i show the values in this same file calling show_DP, next i go to file2.php, I just need to show the values in here with show_DP

Comment: i use File1.php to set and to show the values calling both functions and File2.php just to show the values

Comment: The global $data_person in your code is a $_POST array and it is visible only when the $_POST form is submitted. If you change the page, $_POST array is not called, that's why it is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those values to persist application wide, then you can use sessions for this:

```
// setter function
function receive_DP($data_person_array) {
    $_SESSION['data_person'] = $data_person_array;
}

// getter function
function show_DP() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['data_person'])) {
        $data_person = $_SESSION['data_person'];
        echo "name:".$data_person[0];
        echo "last name:".$data_person[1];
        echo "age".$data_person[2];
    }
}

// clear dp values
function unset_DP() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['data_person'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['data_person'])
    }
}
```

And important reminder: You always need to have `session_start()` on those scripts involved.

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterio the important thing is, you must have `session_start()` at the top of the PHP which will use this PHP functions file. I'm glad this helped, so first line of php file `session_start()`, then second `include 'functions.php';`

Comment: Ok, but when i go back to the previous page the browser shows "Expired Document", and I need the user to be able to go back in order to modify some input values

Comment: When I go from file1.php to file2.php the value of $_SESSION is saved so i can show it in file2.php but when i go back to file1.php the Browser shows that

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterio from `file1.php`, do you use `header('Location: file2.php')`? you must use the post/redirect/get technique so that you wont encounter this. `file1.php`: process form values, set sessions, etc. then header redirect, then upon arrival on `file2.php` use the `show_DP`

Comment: No, i am using a FORM in file1.php with an input type 'submit' and method 'post' to go to file2.php, but when i press the back button of the browser to go back to file1.php the session has expired: "Document Expired"

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterio don't use the form action `file2.php`, instead use the same page `file1.php` which contains the form, use `receive_DP` on `file1.php`, then after all is finished, in the end `header('Location: file2.php')`

Answer (score 1):

do this in file1.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['data_person']=$_POST['data_person'];
```

`$_SESSION['data_person']` is equal to `$_POST['data_person'];`

You can access it any where you want,

**Comment Added:** you can use session_start(); in any file and can access this value. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but i need to do this $data_person=$_SESSION['data_person']?, cause i need to use the variable $data_person

Comment: It doesnt work, I am doing this in file1php:     session_start();       $_SESSION['data_person']=$_POST['data_person']       $data_person = $_SESSION['data_person'];     
receive_DP($data_person);

Comment: It works fine in file1.php but not when i call show_DP() from file2.php, It doesnt show the data, I need to use the variable $data_person not $_SESSION('data_person') cause it is not confortable

Comment: yeah buddy i am using it in file2.php, Do i have to start session in the page where the form is too?

Comment: Do i have to start session in the page where the form is too?